# Tomcat not opening in browser of my machine which i have installed in campus Ubuntu server

Tags: java, ubuntu-16.04

This is the status of tomcat8 in ubuntu server. but i am not able to view it in browser.

```
 tomcat8.service - LSB: Start Tomcat.
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/tomcat8; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
 Active: active (running) since Sat 2017-12-16 15:48:34 IST; 1 day 19h ago
 Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
 Tasks: 51 (limit: 512)
 CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat8.service
       └─28131 /usr/lib/jvm/default-java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config

 Dec 16 15:48:29 dellgpu1-C6100 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Tomcat....
 Dec 16 15:48:29 dellgpu1-C6100 tomcat8[28104]:  * Starting Tomcat servlet engine
 Dec 16 15:48:34 dellgpu1-C6100 tomcat8[28104]:    ...done.
 Dec 16 15:48:34 dellgpu1-C6100 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Tomcat..
 lines 1-12/12 (END)
```

Comment: Check on which port your tomcat is started using "netstat -plnt | grep java" and then try with "http://127.0.0.1:PORT"

Comment: firewall issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the port number in server.xml file

1. Go to tomcat folder>conf
2. open server.xml file and check for connector port number.

In browser open the tomcat home page like
http://SystemIP:connectorPORT

Answer (score 0):

I all tried all possible ways. I couldn't do anything, then i contacted network administrator of my campus he solved the issue. It was a firewall issue. Thank you